# Showing that any two separable closures of a field are $K$-isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

> We call a ﬁeld $F$ called separably closed if the only separable algebraic extension $F\subset E$ is the trivial extension, that is $E=F$. A separable closure of a ﬁeld $K$ is a separable algebraic extension $K \subset K_s$, with $K_s$ separably closed. 
> Q: Show that every field $K$ has a separable extension; furthermore, show that any two separable closures of $K$ are $K$-isomorphic.

Now I'm having a bit of a problem with this exercise I found in one of my old books about field theory. To begin with, this definition to me seems a bit odd, since it's not clear at all to me that such a separable closure $K_s$ should even exist for any field $K$. Maybe I'm missing something crucial here? 
Anyhow, for the first part of this exercise I was so far only able to show that $K_s$ (if it exists) is indeed a field. I don't think that's what the question is asking tho'. But the part I mostly need help with is the last part of the question; I haven't been able to make much progress at all.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Is there any other description for the fields $K$? For a field with characteristic $0$ every irreducible polynomial is separable. Hence, every extension of a characteristic $0$ field is separable. For positive characteristic this is only necessarily the case for finite extension of finite fields.

Comment: For the second part: are you familiar with the proof that any two algebraic closures of a field are isomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that for arbitrary extension $K \subset L$, $K_{s} = \{x \in K \mid \text{ x is separable and algebraic over $K$}\}$ is a subfield of $L$. Now apply this to $K \subset \overline{K}$ to show that $K_{s}$ is a separable closure of $K$.
2. Let $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ be separable closures of $K$. Let $\overline{K}$ be the algebraic closure of $K$. Then we can find subfields $L_{1}, L_{2}$ of $\overline{K}$ along with the isomorphisms $\phi_{1} \colon K_{1} \xrightarrow{\sim} L_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}\colon K_{2} \xrightarrow{\sim} L_{2}$. Then $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are separable closures of $K$ in $\overline{K}$. Hence $L_{1} = L_{2}$ (since they are both maximal separable extensions of $K$ in $\overline{K}$). Thus $K_{1} \xrightarrow{\phi_{1}} L_{1} = L_{2} \xrightarrow{\phi_{2}^{-1}} K_{2}$ and any two separable closures are isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that I grasped the second question now, but I'm still having a bit of trouble with the first one. Can you please explain a bit more, I don't really understand what you mean by "Now apply this to...".

Comment: @ThoraN $K_{s}$ of an arbitrary extension $K \subset L$ as defined is the subfield algebraic and separable elements in $L$. Now if we consider $L = \overline{K}$, then $K_{s} = \{x \in \overline{K} \mid \text{ x is separable over $K$}\}$ is a subfield of $\overline{K}$ and the separable closure of $K$.